# ajax in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am developing application in asp.net,i want to know how can we use ajax in asp.net 2.0
   can any one please help me with your valuble answers.

thanks in advance
sangita

Comment: http://www.lmgtfy.com/?q=asp.net+ajax -.-

Answer (score 1):

You can have [Microsoft implementation of AJAX](http://www.asp.net/ajax/) or you can write [Ajax codes on your own](http://www.w3schools.com/Ajax/Default.Asp) or you can have javascript frameworks like [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax) which have built in Ajax functionality.